# Moodle: where does Moodle save webservice tokens?

Tags: moodle

I have successfully enabled webservices on Moodle and also developed my own.
In order to use the webservice from  client, I had to create a user token.
That token is automatically generated. It happened that for some unknown reason, the token I had in my production site is gone. The problem is that all apps currently using the webservice have the token hard-coded. So If I generate a new token in moodle I'll have to distribute a new version of the App and this could be a problem. But if I find where Moodle saves the tokens (perhaps in moodlebd?) I can try to force the new token to the one that is currently hard coded in my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I've found it. It's `mdl_external_tokens` table of Moodle database